# Padding Sequences: max length way above average length

Tags: python, keras, padding, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm implementing an LSTM network for sentiment analysis. Problem is I'm using max-length padding, but the max-length of my data (1052) is way above the average of 133. Setting the input length of my network to this max length drastically increases training time. How should I deal with this ? Building my network using keras library.

Comment: Depends what are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you using the `Masking` layer? Or are you setting `mask_zero=True` in the Embedding layer?

Comment: I'm setting it to True